# Invalid MEX-file '/home/hit/caffe-master/matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.mexa64':

Tags: matlab, caffe

When I run classification_demo.m which is in /caffe-master/matlab/demo,I got the error message,how to fix it? [image]

Comment: For future questions, please don't use photos for error message. Instead copy / write the text into your question, this allows search engines to work!

Comment: OK, thank you for your advice!